# Meteor: How do I make dburles:collection-helpers work with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, join, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use `urigo:angular` with `dburles:collection-helpers` but I can't figure out what the syntax should be.

This is what I had using just Meteor:

```
Template.books.helpers({  
    books: function() {
        return Books.find();
    },
    authors: function() {
        return Authors.find();
    },
    author: function() {
        return Authors.findOne(this.authorId);
    }
});
```

And in the view:

```
<template name="books">  
    <h1>Books!</h1>
    <ol>
        {{#each books}}
            <li>{{name}} by {{author.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
</template>
```

That worked fine.

Now I've added Angular and I'm changing to this (author doesn't work):

```
$scope.books = $meteor.collection(function(){
    return Books.find({})
});

$scope.authors = $meteor.collection(function(){
    return Authors.find({})
});

$scope.author = $meteor.collection(function(){
    return Authors.findOne(this.authorId);
});
```

And the view to this:

```
<li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.name}} by {{author.name}}</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular you are binding the result to `$scope.author` and not the function itself. When you're calling

```
$scope.author = $meteor.collection(function() {
    return Authors.findOne(this.authorId);
}
```

`this` is referring to the controller (actually I think it's referring to the collection method... either way), not the book.
Besides, angular-meteor does not have a `findOne` method, you simple add `{limit: 1}` or use `$meteor.object`

To get a similar result to what you're doing then in your controller you could do something like:

```
function MainController($scope, $meteor) {
    $scope.books = $meteor.collection(function () {
        return Books.find({});
    });

    $scope.authors = $meteor.collection(function () {
        return Authors.find({});
    });

    $scope.author = function (book) {
       return $meteor.object(Authors, book.authorId, false);
    }
}
```

`$meteor.object` is what you'll use instead of findOne. Now in the html you'll need to call the function:

```
<li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.name}} by: {{author(this.book).name}}</li>
```

The function is returns the author object, the of course you access the name.

Here's a [Meteor Pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/wBgmwdAHztgMXKyF4/Angular-meteor%20example)

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. If I want to display all comments where the bookId is equal to this book's id? I've tried the following with no luck:
    $scope.comments = function (book) {
        return $meteor.object(Comments, {bookId: book._id()}, false);
    }

Comment: comments would be a collection instead of an object.

Comment: $scope.comments = function (book) { return $meteor.collection(Comments, {bookId: book._id()}, false); } doesn't seem to work

Comment: I haven't tested this on collections personally, but what is `{boodId: book._id()}` why the "()" at the end of book._id?

Comment: Without the "()" it doesn't work either. I'm trying to display all "comments" in the collection "Comments" that have a "bookId" equal to this.book's "_id"